# Does Visual Studio Code have smart tag editing (like WebStorm)?

Tags: webstorm, visual-studio-code

So when you have a closed tag and when you start editing first part it automatically edit second one for you.

It works in WebStorm and I'm missing this functionality in VSC.

Is it possible to switch it on or install any plugin for it?

Comment: Natively it doesn't have smart tags, but it will highlight unclosed ones automatically.

Comment: ok,thx for feedback, looks like first minus for me comparing to webstorm

Comment: Not familiar with VSC .. but even in WebStorm such _simultaneous automatic_ editing was introduced only recently (2016.1 I believe) -- before that you had to invoke `Refactor | Rename` to have the same result (in other words: now it's just made simpler). Maybe VCS supports something like that via some Refactor equivalent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VSCode doesn't do this "native", but as with many features, there is an extension for this: [Auto Rename Tag](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.auto-rename-tag)